# How can I convert this C# foreach code to C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am making tic tac toe game on the visual studio window form with c++.
How can I convert this C# code to C++ code?

```
private Void disableButtons()
{
    try
    { 
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
        Button b = (Button)c;
        b.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    catch{ }
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using? MFC?

Comment: As in how to convert the foreach or how to actually make buttons work in C++?  One is trivial, one is not.

Comment: I want to convert the foreach loop for c++

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert it into pure C++ code without using any additional libraries that have classes **Control** and **Button** with Button class having an "Enabled" public member.
You can however convert it to **C++/CLI** code where you can mix pure C++ code too.

```
private Void disableButtons()
{
    try
    { 
        for each (Control^ c in Controls)
        {
            Button^ b = (Button^)c;
            b->Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    catch{ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use the `foreach` of C# in c++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 3;
    int myArray[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    for (int & i : myArray) // make sure to put the &
    {
        i = i + 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << myArray[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The syntax should be like this:

```
for(type name : collection) { // your code here  }
```

and you can put & between type and name if you want to change the original elements

`for(type & name : collection) { // your code here  }`

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this Visual C++ so I'm presuming you're using MFC. The answer would be different if you're using Qt or wxWidgets or something else.

If you already have the control ID's in a container that you want to for-each on, then:

```
UINT Controls[] = { IDC_BUTTON1, IDC_BUTTON2, IDC_BUTTON3, IDC_BUTTON4, IDC_BUTTON5 };

for (UINT c : Controls)
{
    CWnd *b = GetDlgItem(c);
    if (b)
        b->EnableWindow(FALSE);
}
```

If however you don't have such a container of controls but somehow want to still iterate all the controls then:

```
CWnd *c = GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
while (c)
    {
    c->EnableWindow(FALSE);
    c = c->GetNextWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT);
    }
```

I recommend the first option because then you can be specific about which controls you want to modify. The second option will be tricky if you only want buttons.